# Numpy's standard deviation method giving divide by zero error

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a function to regularise a set of features in a machine learning algorithm. It takes a rectangular 2D numpy array `features` and returns its regularised version `reg_features` (I am using the Boston housing prices data from Scikit-learn for training). The exact code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from pprint import pprint

def regularise(features):

    # Regularised features:
    reg_features = np.zeros(features.shape)

    for x in range(len(features)):
        for y in range(len(features[x])):

            reg_features[x][y] = (features[x][y] - np.mean(features[:, y])) / np.std(features[:, y])

    return reg_features

# Get the data
total_features, total_prices = load_boston(True)

# Keep 300 samples for training
train_features = regularise(total_features[:300])        # Works OK
train_prices = total_prices[:300]

# Keep 100 samples for validation
valid_features = regularise(total_features[300:400])     # Works OK
valid_prices = total_prices[300:400]

# Keep remaining samples as test set
test_features = regularise(total_features[400:])         # Does not work
test_prices = total_prices[400:]
```

Note that the I only get this error for the last call to `regularise()`, the one with `total_features[400:]`:

> /Users/RohanSaxena/Documents/projects/sdc/tensor/reg.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>     reg_features[x][y] = (features[x][y] - np.mean(features[:, y])) / np.std(features[:, y])

The rest of this code is with respect to the last call, that is `regularise(total_features[400:])`

To check if one of the standard deviations is a zero, I do this:

```
for y in range(len(features[0])):
    if np.std(features[:, y]) == 0.:
        print(np.std(features[:, y])
```

Which prints all zeros, that is:

```
0.0
0.0
...
0.0
```

a total of `features[0].size` times. This means that the standard deviation of every column in `features` is zero.

Now this seems very odd. So I print every single standard deviation to be sure:

```
for y in range(len(features[0])):
    print(np.std(features[:, y])
```

I get all **non zero** values:

```
10.9976293017
23.3483275632
6.63216140033
....
8.00329244499
```

How is this possible? Just before, prefixed by an `if` condition, this same code had given me all zeros, and now it gives non-zero values! This doesn't make any sense to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make it much easier to debug this.

Comment: You may reproduce the same situation by calling reg() with the Boston dataset imported from sklearn

Comment: It works fine for me. I don't get a warning, and I don't get 0 values in the loop that you show having 0.0 output.  Can you show the *exact* code that you run in order to generate that warning?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Added the code that's troubling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the subset of the data `total_features[400:]` that results in the problem. If you look at that data, you'll see that columns `total_features[400:, 1]` and `total_features[400:, 3]` are all 0.  This causes a problem in your code, because the both the mean and standard deviation of those columns are 0, resulting in 0/0.

Instead of writing your own regularize function, you could use [`sklearn.preprocessing.scale`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html). That function handles a constant column by returning a column that is all 0.

You can easily verify that `scale` does the same calculation as your `regularise`:

```
In [68]: test
Out[68]: 
array([[ 15.,   1.,   0.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.,   1.]])

In [69]: regularise(test)
Out[69]: 
array([[ 1.41421356, -1.41421356, -1.20560706],
       [-1.41421356, -0.70710678,  0.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.72336423],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.44672847],
       [ 0.70710678,  1.41421356, -0.96448564]])

In [70]: from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

In [71]: scale(test)
Out[71]: 
array([[ 1.41421356, -1.41421356, -1.20560706],
       [-1.41421356, -0.70710678,  0.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.72336423],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.44672847],
       [ 0.70710678,  1.41421356, -0.96448564]])
```

The following shows how the functions handle a column of zeros:

```
In [72]: test[:,2] = 0

In [73]: test
Out[73]: 
array([[ 15.,   1.,   0.],
       [  3.,   4.,   0.],
       [  6.,   7.,   0.],
       [  9.,  10.,   0.],
       [ 12.,  13.,   0.]])

In [74]: regularise(test)
/Users/warren/miniconda3/bin/ipython:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
Out[74]: 
array([[ 1.41421356, -1.41421356,         nan],
       [-1.41421356, -0.70710678,         nan],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        ,         nan],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,         nan],
       [ 0.70710678,  1.41421356,         nan]])

In [75]: scale(test)
Out[75]: 
array([[ 1.41421356, -1.41421356,  0.        ],
       [-1.41421356, -0.70710678,  0.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.        ],
       [ 0.70710678,  1.41421356,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks, you have identified the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when that happens first guess would be you are dividing the numerator by an int (rather than a float) larger than it, so the result is 0. However that does not seen to be the case here.

Sometimes the division is not doing what you expected it to be doing (term by term), rather, its an vector operation.
However thats also not the case here.

The issue here is how you reference your dataframe

```
reg_features[x][y]
```

when dealing with dataframe and realocating values to specific cells you want to use the function `loc`

You can read more about it here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html